# Visual Studio debugger points at operator where no such exception could ever be

Tags: c#, debugging

I encountered strange behavior of Visual Studio as debugger: when `NullRefereneException` occurs, the debugger points at operator where such sort of exception could never be. My code is pretty basic:

```
{
 for (int i = 0; i < employmentAccounts1.Count(); i++)
  employmentAccountsCommon[i] = (object)employmentAccounts1[i];
}
```

The debugger points at operator `i++`, please see the screen.[image] The value of `i` variable at this point is 0, not null. And there is no way of `i` becoming null ever, considering this code fragment. The value of `employmentAccounts1.Count()` is 3, and the error happens at the second pass of the cycle (when `i` is still 0, as was previously mentioned)

So, what is this? Is it a bug in Visual Studio? I first encountered this behavior on Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2008. Presuming this was a bug, I installed Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2022 Community edition. But the behavior now appears to be the same. So again, what is this? If this is a bug, how did it survive for so long? If this is not a bug, then what is this and how such behavior could be amended or worked around? In other words, how to force Visual Studio to point at the correct line of code? I just cannot debug my application now because of this behavior. Can anybody help?

Comment: Are you debugging using the Debug configuration? What type of application is this?

Comment: check before running zhe loop if employmentAccounts1 is NULL

Comment: Thank you, @gunr2171 but I am not sure what is Debug configuration. Could you please explain?

Comment: @nbk, it is as I said "The value of employmentAccounts1.Count() is 3", which unambiguously means that employmentAccounts1 is not null

Comment: and which size has employmentAccountsCommon, it must have at least 3

Comment: @nbk, thank you very much. That indeed was the reason, i.e. that employmentAccountsCommon was null, since it was defined as object[] employmentAccountsCommon = null;  Now that I've redefined this variable as new fixed size array, like this: var employmentAccountsCommon = new object[printFrom == 0 ? employmentAccounts.Count() : employmentAccounts1.Count()];
there is no error. Thank you. But what about the question on top of this discussion - Visual Studio points at i++ operator as the source of error. Is this a bug, or what?

Comment: Everything in the parenthesis belongs to the loop so no bug there, the error could be a bit clearer

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand you. The debugger points to the wrong operator, and as a result of this I was unable to debug my code. How this could be "no bug there"? The debugger must have been pointing to the employmentAccountsCommon[i] = (object)employmentAccounts1[i]; operator

Comment: When compiling with Release configuration, the compiler may apply additional optimizations which makes it hard for the debugger to pick the correct code section.

Comment: Thank you, @KlausGütter. Do I understand you right - if I somehow manage to compile my application with Debug configuration, the debugger will then point at the correct operator, i.e. 'employmentAccountsCommon[i] = (object)employmentAccounts1[i];'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As nobody cares to answer this question, I presume it’s my duty to do it.
The situation where Visual Studio debugger points at the wrong statement as the source of error is not a bug but a feature. Because when code is compiled with optimization, it’s hard to determine the correct source of error. The solution is, for purpose of debugging, to compile your code without optimization. That’s it, if I correctly understood my respondents